# Centering text within div using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to familiarize myself with Bootstrap and its grid system. Below shows my attempt at creating a footer, I wouldn't like to use all 12 cols, at the moment it looks fine - but for some reason I am unable to center the list items within the div. I've tried playing with Google dev tools but can't really find the reason why.

```
.wrapper{
    width:80%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.footer{
    margin:0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML

```
  <div class="row footer">
            <div class="wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="col-md-2 ">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                        <li>Bob</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working as expected, what are you trying to achieve? The items centered within their lists, or the lists centered in the footer?

Comment: `col-*` should be the immediate children of `row`

Comment: Col-*s are set to float:left by default in bootstrap we need a reset Check th link https://jsfiddle.net/7acynjLj/1/

Answer (score 0):

use

```
.footer ul {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

[demo](https://codepen.io/mrinal013/pen/ZJMPXY)